# I would like to know is there a better way to design my page without using foreach mulitple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to know is there a better way to design my page without using foreach mulitple times.  I have 3 column that will contain data.  However I have to use a foreach in each column in order to display the data.

What would be the best way to handle.

I am using an IEnumerable.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
            if (item.PageContentSeqNbr == 2)
            {
                <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
            }
        }
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
            if (item.PageContentSeqNbr == 3)
            {
                <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
            }
        }

        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
            if (item.PageContentSeqNbr == 4)
            {
                <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
            }
        }
       <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems like it might be a good idea to move this logic to the server side, but its difficult to tell based on your example.

Comment: Use a view model with properties for each of the 3 collections. At least you can avoid looping the whole collection 3 times, and then you can use a custom EditorTemplate for your model and just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstCollection)` instead

Comment: You shouldnt need this level of complexity in your view - either be more selective in your db calls or sort out the complexity in your controller or when you build your view model. What parameters are used to call up this view?

Answer (score 0):

A little better? Few people might agree, or not.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.PageContentSeqNbr == 2))
     {
        var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
        <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
    }
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.PageContentSeqNbr == 3))
     {
        var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
        <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
    }
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.PageContentSeqNbr == 4))
     {
        var desc = item.PageContentLongDesc;
        <p> @Html.Raw(@desc)</p>
    }
   <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I like that.

I decided to try and use Html.Action and PartialView.